# Connecting k8s services in GKE cross-region clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using GKE with Cloud VPN and have the following architecture: [GKE example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ytHk.png)

In the VPC there are two k8s clusters in different regions and one Cloud VPN. We’re trying to use internal services (internal load balancers) via the VPN and from the k8s clusters to each other. This doesn’t work because the internal load balancer is a regional product.

What is the correct way to let (internal) services in k8s connect to each other across clusters in different regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing your message and the architecture, I am assuming that both k8s clusters are created within the same VPC. Creating cloud VPN within the same VPC is not a feasible option to try for your use case. Rather you can create two different k8s clusters in two different VPCs and connect through VPN. While configuring the VPN for both sides make sure you select the regions(the VPN tunnel and the internal load balancer must be in the same region) accordingly.

Traffic from your clients reach the internal load balancer in the [VPC network through Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/#deploying_internal_load_balancing_with_clients_across_vpn_or_interconnect) and I hope this way the (internal) services in k8s will be able to connect with each other across clusters in different regions.